# On the end of something

Tags: prepositions

I read this in OALD about Noddy by Enid Blyton:

"Noddy is a small boy with a large head on which he wears a long blue cap with a bell on the end of it."
I'm quite familiar with how "in the end" and "at the end" are used, but "on the end (of sth) is new to me.Does it simply have the same meaning as "at the end" as it refers to the end of a physical object? If not, how is it different from the other two phrases?

Answer (score 2):

"in the end" refers to time, or to a process that takes time.  It's an idiom for "finally" or "after all" ([dictionary.com definition 38](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in--the--end))

> In the end, I was able to escape.

"at the end" is used more literally.  It can refer to time, or it can refer to an object or a place.

> At the end of my life, I hope I find inner peace.
>
> At the end of the hallway there's a fax machine.
>
> You'll see an emergency stop button at the end of the conveyer belt.

"on the end" is used literally as well; it refers to an object.

> On the end of the rope, tie a safety harness.

These are general rules, of course.  Nothing about English prepositions is ever 100%.

Comment: +1.  "On" is being used pretty literally here, as it often is when we refer to long skinny things.  The cap has an end, and *on* that end is a bell.